# MVC Save user AD Information to Database as soon as site is access the firsttime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Windows authentication in MVC. Once a user access a webpage for the first time via intranet I want to store the User's Active Directory guid, and a datetime stamp the user's accessed the site into a database.

I know how to get the user's information form active directory. The question is where do I put that method so that it is only called once the user's accesses the site the first time and not on every page request.

Comment: Are you having performance issues accessing user information from active directory?  Because it doesn't make sense to duplicate data, what happens if the data changes in active directory.  What you are doing does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: The application is used only by select users within active directory. Therefore once they access it I just want to save a record that it has been access by the following user.

Comment: There is now conflicting information between your question and your comment.  Do you want to `save some of the user's Active directory information into the database` or `I just want to save a record that it has been access by the following user`?

Comment: To be more specific I would like to save the User's Active Directory guid, and a datetime stamp of any user's that has accessed the site.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating an [ActionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
public class ADUserActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    // Do database stuff
  }
}
```

In your /App_Start/FilterConfig.cs add it as a global filter:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
  public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
  {
    filters.Add(new ADUserActionFilterAttribute());
  }
}
```

On each request by anyone you can verify the user is in the database (and optionally update the last time they used the website).

> The question is where do I put that method so that it is only called once the user's accesses the site the first time and not on every page request.

This logic does not exist natively in the ASP.Net pipeline, so you will have to create it yourself.  At some point, you will *have* to go to the database to see if the record exist.